# Joomla check for empty string with JInput

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Following this [guide](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) to sanitize my inputs, I'm wondering if an empty string is covered with this?

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$this->name = $jinput->get('name', '', 'STRING');
```

Typically without Joomla I'd be checking for an empty string as well. Something like:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name']))
```

Looking at the JInput get method I see that it checks if it is `isset`:

```
public function get($name, $default = null, $filter = 'cmd')
{
    if (isset($this->data[$name]))
    {
        return $this->filter->clean($this->data[$name], $filter);
    }

    return $default;
}
```

Not the same thing, as `isset` will only check for null. However that is the default value for using the get method. So if I specify an empty string for the second parameter am I covered here?

```
$this->name = $jinput->get('name', '', 'STRING');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not up to Joomla to decide whether your empty string is valid value or not. They have to use `isset()`, because if they would use `empty()` and you return `'0'` which you would expect as normal, Joomla would return default value instead of that `'0'`.

So it's completely normal that they just use `isset()` to check if variable is set, and it's up to you to decide what values you accept.

If the value isn't set, and you set as the second parameter empty string `''`, you'll get an empty string returned.

In your example an empty string would be returned, which is expected behaviour.